# Guice provider that can access a JAX-RS POST object

Tags: jax-rs, guice, resteasy

I am attempting to use both Guice with JAX-RS such that I can create a Provider with request scope to instantiate objects. However, in one provider, I wish to be able to access the object that was created from the POST body. For example:

```
@RequestScoped
class MonkeyProvider implements Provider<Monkey> {
    @Inject private Banana banana;

    Monkey get() {
       // Need access to the Banana that was posted!
    }
}

class MyResource {
    @Inject private MonkeyProvider monkeyProvider;

    @POST
    @Path("/test")
    void test(Banana banana) {
        monkeyProvider.get();
    }
}
```

I know that I can inject UriInfo to get path parameters and query parameters, but is there any way to get the actual body object that was POSTed?

Comment: Just pass it as an argument. That would be a _lot_ easier than any other solution (if there _is_ another solution).